# Does Outlook embed a MessageID or equivalent in its email elements?

Tags: c#, automation, outlook, outlook-addin

I want to automate Outlook so that I can download the "pieces parts" of email messages so that I can tie related messages together. I understand that email usually has a "MessageID" to serve this purpose, so that emails can be viewed in context, as "threads" in a newsreader are tied together.

Does Outlook have the notion of "Message IDs" in emails sent with it? I see that the elements that can be extracted (using automation) are Subject, SenderEmail, CreationTime, Body, SenderName, and HTMLBody. Is a "message id" or equivalent available somewhere, too?

Comment: I always thought that Outlook did this by the email subject since when you go to 'find related messages' it just looks in the subject of emails

Comment: I did a quick search - maybe this might help: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/do-get-mail-items-messageid-t2968634.html

Comment: @Charleh - Subject would work most of the time, but not always, as sometimes people change the subject - especially when the direction of the conversation has shifted.

Comment: @Bridge: I think it's Outlook 2003 (I'm not at work now, as it's 2 a.m., but I'm pretty sure that's the version. Also: thanks for the link; it looks like "Subject" will have to suffice.

Comment: @ClayShannon I _think_ (my experience is more with `SMTPClient` than Outlook interop) that Exchange server might set a different MessageID before it goes off "out into the world" anyway - but I'm no expert on that side of things I'm afraid!

Comment: @Bridge: Yes, I verified it's Outlook 2003.

Comment: If you are interested please commit for this :http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/outlook-addin/commit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Outlook tracks related messages by using **Conversations**.

In Outlook 2003, there is [`ConversationTopic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms527833%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx) (*MAPI: `PR_CONVERSATION_TOPIC`*) & [`ConversationIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms528174%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx) 
(*MAPI: `PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX`*). `ConversationTopic` is typically the message subject (*minus prefixes - RE:/FW:, etc.*), while `ConversationIndex` represents the sequential ordering of the `ConversationTopic` (*essentially GUID + timestamp*). See [Working with Conversations on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms528195%28v=exchg.10%29). `ConversationIndex` is [explicitly defined on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc765583.aspx).

In Outlook 2010, they added [`ConversationID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.conversationid.aspx) (*MAPI: `PR_CONVERSATION_ID`*) which is derived from the `ConversationTopic`. `ConversationID` can be generated from the `ConversationTopic` as [discussed here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/outlookdev/thread/0d0a9672-c4b6-49f7-a93d-12be2dc5cc36/).

For more detailed info about the MSG protocol specs regarding **Conversations** see [[MS-OXOMSG]: E-Mail Object Protocol Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc433482%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx), section 2.2.1.2 and 2.2.1.3.

Answer (score 2):

Small addition to previous great answer. In case if anyone else will also need C# implementation of [algorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff387041%28v=office.12%29.aspx) used to retrieve ConversationID from ConversationIndex/ConversationTopic:

```
private const int c_ulConvIndexIDOffset = 6;
private const int c_ulConvIndexIDLength = 16;

private string GetConversationId()
        {
            var convTracking = GetMapiPropertyBool(PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX_TRACKING);
            var convIndex = GetMapiPropertyBytes(PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX);
            byte[] idBytes;
            if (convTracking
                && convIndex != null
                && convIndex.Length > 0)
            {
                // get Id from Conversation index
                idBytes = new byte[c_ulConvIndexIDLength];
                Array.Copy(convIndex, c_ulConvIndexIDOffset, idBytes, 0, c_ulConvIndexIDLength);
            }
            else
            {
                // get Id from Conversation topic
                var topic = GetMapiPropertyString(PR_CONVERSATION_TOPIC);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(topic))
                {
                    return string.Empty;
                }

                if (topic.Length >= 265)
                {
                    topic = topic.Substring(0, 256);
                }
                topic = topic.ToUpper();

                using (var md5 = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
                {
                    idBytes = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(topic));
                }
            }

            return BitConverter.ToString(idBytes).Replace("-", string.Empty);
        }
```

GetMapiProperty...() is a helper functions which just retrieve required MAPI property and cast result to appropriate managed type

Comment: How is ConversationTopic (assigned to topic) instantiated?

Comment: I've corrected code. It's just a value of PR_CONVERSATION_TOPIC MAPI property